# slice Pytorch tensors which are saved in a list

Tags: pytorch, tensor, pyro

I have the following code segment to generate random samples. The generated `samples` is a `list`, where each entry of the list is a `tensor`. Each tensor has two elements. I would like to extract the first element from all tensors in the list; and extract the second element from all tensors in the list as well. How to perform this kind of tensor slice operation

```
import torch
import pyro.distributions as dist
num_samples = 250
# note that both covariance matrices are diagonal
mu1 = torch.tensor([0., 5.])
sig1 = torch.tensor([[2., 0.], [0., 3.]])
dist1 = dist.MultivariateNormal(mu1, sig1)
samples1 = [pyro.sample('samples1', dist1) for _ in range(num_samples)]

samples1
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend `torch.cat` with a list comprehension:

```py
col1 = torch.cat([t[0] for t in samples1])
col2 = torch.cat([t[1] for t in samples1])
```

Docs for `torch.cat`: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.cat.html

ALTERNATIVELY

You could turn your list of 1D tensors into a single big 2D tensor using `torch.stack`, then do a normal slice:

```py
samples1_t = torch.stack(samples1)
col1 = samples1_t[:, 0]  # : means all rows
col2 = samples1_t[:, 1]
```

Docs for `torch.stack`: https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.stack.html

Answer (score 0):

I should mention PyTorch tensors come with unpacking out of the box, this means you can unpack the first axis into multiple variables without additional considerations. Here [`torch.stack`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.stack.html) will output a tensor of shape `(rows, cols)`, we just need to [transpose](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.t.html) it to `(cols, rows)` and [unpack](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-tuple-list-unpack/):

```
>>> c1, c2 = torch.stack(samples1).T
```

So you get `c1` and `c2` shaped `(rows,)`:

```
>>> c1
tensor([0.6433, 0.4667, 0.6811, 0.2006, 0.6623, 0.7033])

>>> c2
tensor([0.2963, 0.2335, 0.6803, 0.1575, 0.9420, 0.6963])
```

Answer (score 0):

Other answers that suggest `.stack()` or `.cat()` are perfectly fine from PyTorch perspective.

However, since the context of the question involves `pyro`, may I add the following:

Since you are doing IID samples

```
[pyro.sample('samples1', dist1) for _ in range(num_samples)]
```

A better way to do it with `pyro` is

```
dist1 = dist.MultivariateNormal(mu1, sig1).expand([num_samples])
```

This tells `pyro` that the distribution is *batched* with a batch size of `num_samples`. Sampling from this will produce

```
>> dist1.sample()
tensor([[-0.8712,  6.6087],
    [ 1.6076, -0.2939],
    [ 1.4526,  6.1777],
    ...
    [-0.0168,  7.5085],
    [-1.6382,  2.1878]])
```

Now its easy to solve your original question. Just slice it like

```
samples = dist1.sample()
samples[:, 0]  # all first elements
samples[:, 1]  # all second elements
```